# Indicador espera vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Tengo una aplicación web programada con vb.net, en la que se hacen consultas a Base de datos y se consumen WebServices, y en algunos casos, estas operaciones toman bastante tiempo. Querría indicar de alguna manera al usuario, que la aplicación está desarrollando estas operaciones, puesto que en algunos casos da la sensación de que no se está haciendo nada

```
 ' Mostrar indicador espera
  OperacionBaseDatos()
  LlamadaWebService()
 ' Ocultar indicador espera
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma sencilla sería sacar una ventana de espera. Diseñas el form de espera sin ControlBox (en adelante, WaitForm), lo muestras antes y lo ocultas después.

```
Dim x As New WaitForm()
x.Show()
OperacionBaseDatos()
LlamadaWebService()
x.Close()
```

Comment: Disculpa la pregunta, pero trabajo poco con vb.net, ¿me podrías pasar un enlace con algún ejemplo de un form sin ControlBox como el qué dices? He buscado y no encuentro nada que me pueda ayudar. Gracias!

Comment: Lo más sencillo es a través del diseñador gráfico de windows forms. Crea un formulario y llámalo, por ejemplo, WaitForm, lo diseñas con el diseñador, pequeño, poniendo la propiedad ControlBox del formulario a False y añadiendo una Label que ponga algo como "Por favor, espere". Después, lo llamas desde el código como arriba.